# national characters/unicode characters extract from PDF C#

Tags: pdf, itext, tesseract, pdfsharp

I'm using Tesseract and wrapper - [tesseract.net](https://github.com/tvn-cosine/tesseract.net) version 4.0.0.16

By using this wrapper i create serchable Pdf.

```
tessBaseAPI.SetInputName(imagePath);

        using (var pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(outputName, tessDataPath, false))
        {
            pdfRenderer.BeginDocument(filename);
            pdfRenderer.AddImage(tessBaseAPI);
            pdfRenderer.EndDocument();              
        }
```

Next I use  [PDFsharp-MigraDoc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PDFsharp-MigraDoc/1.50.4619-beta4c) version 1.50.4619-beta4c

to compress PDF and save as stream

```
Stream pdf = new MemoryStream();    
PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument document = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(filePath);
document.Options.FlateEncodeMode = PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfFlateEncodeMode.BestCompression;
document.Options.UseFlateDecoderForJpegImages = PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfUseFlateDecoderForJpegImages.Automatic;
document.Options.NoCompression = false;
document.Options.CompressContentStreams = true;
document.Save(pdf);
```

At the end I use [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/) version 5.5.13

to extract text from PDF. PDF is read as byte[]

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file);
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(llx,lly,urx,ury);
RenderFilter[] filter = { new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect) };
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter);
string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, currentpage, strategy);
currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
sb.Append(currentText);
```

But my problem is iTexSharp extract text without national characters.

For example:

In PDF is line: "Spółka z ograniczoną odpowiedzialnością - Spółka"
When I open it in Firefox/ Chrome/ AdobeReader next the line is copied as "Spółka z ograniczoną odpowiedzialnością - Spółka"
But in iTextSharp this line is extracted as "SpóBka z ograniczon\u0005 odpowiedzialno[ci\u0005 \u0014 SpóBka"

These are extracted unicode characters:

"ą" = "\u0005"

"-" = "\u0014"

"ę" = "\u0019"

"ć" = "\a"

"ś" = "["

"ł" = "B"

"ó" = "ó"

Do you have any idea where I could change Encoding or Language to make it work properly. I would like to notice that in PDFsharp-MigraDoc I have to open existing file. Also when I skip compression PDFsharp-MigraDoc part, iTextSharp work exactly the same

I can't find any property/option/setting to change encoding.
Do you have any idea how to do it or something else?

Comment: Why do you use the [MigraDoc] tag? You do not use MigraDoc at all. Why do you use the [PDFsharp] tag? Issue still occurs when you do not invoke PDFsharp. Are you sure that the string returned by `GetTextFromPage` is not already Unicode? PDF files use PDF encoding (mostly identical to ANSI encoding) or Unicode. Maybe `ASCIIEncoding.Convert` makes things worse.

Comment: You're right, I removed MigraDoc tag. sorry for that.
I use PDFsharp tag with the hope that will be able to change encoding.
Even if i remove `currentText = Encoding...` line, currentText it's still the same.